# Оптимизация INSERT MySQL, как настроить сервер?

Tags: mysql, производительность

Имеется такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `w2b` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wordId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `blockId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `w2b` (`wordId`,`blockId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4057099 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

После 2,5 млн записей скорость вставки резко падает.

Что можно предпринять в плане настройки сервера MySQL, чтобы увеличить скорость хотя бы при 10 млн записей?

Без отключения индексов импорт 4 млн записей выполняется 2 часа.

MariaDB 10.3 x64

Comment: а как вставка происходит? и почему не отключить индексы?

Comment: @teran Отключать в php скрипте при вставке 1 записи индексы?

Comment: А как php скрипт производит вставки, используется ли групповая вставка, сделан ли 1 prepare и потом множественный execute. Сделан ли коммит транзакции не после каждой вставки а какими нибудь блоками. Если при вставке явно указывается id идет ли вставка в порядке следования id. Если все это уже предусмотрено то боюсь сделать уже ничего нельзя не перенося таблицу на более быстрый носитель

Comment: @Mike Множественных вставок нету, они просто тормозят. Препаре для одной записи в одну единицу времени не имеет смысла, да есть препаре. Тут для начала, про то как настроить сервер, ибо я так думаю, человек который ставил скрипт просто не делал этого от слова совсем.

Comment: @Mike и да я подозреваю что дело еще в HDD

Comment: Смотрите статистику innodb и изучайте документацию по этому вопросу. пересказывать десятки страниц документации тут нет смысла, а без полного их понимания ничего все равно не настроите. А вообще дефолтные настройки более чем оптимальны для вставки отдельных записей. конечно при условии что выделено достаточно оперативной памяти и при этом mysql не выпадает в свап. Если при этих условиях тормозит, значит данные вставляются в слишком случайном порядке и индекс сильно перестраивается. Еще имеет смысл отказаться от поля id, оно тут лишнее, если на запись не ссылаются из других таблиц

Comment: ну так откуда я должен знать что вы по одной вставляете, вы про 2.5млн пишите. вы же не потрудились объяснить, как вы вообще вставляете записи